# Does the app get auto resized?

Tags: ios, iphone, resize, app-store

Does the application get auto resized when uploaded to the AppStore to fit all devices like iPhone 5 and iPhone 7+ ?

I'm asking this because I'm about to release a new app for the Appstore but in the simulator and on a real device the application doesn't gets resized and all the buttons and label etc are not where they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also developing an iOS app, so I understand your problem.

The application **doesn't** get resized.

The buttons/labels won't be put wherever they should be as Xcode **doesn't know** where to put them. This is because the screen size varies with each device.

You should use constraints ([really good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iT9fueKCJM)) to put your buttons/labels wherever you want them to be. [Another good tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not automatic. You need to design your app to handle layouts on different devices. It's a rather complex subject. You'll need to learn about AutoLayout and size classes, among other topics. If your app isn't handling this correctly, it's not ready for the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check your application is universal application .

Then You need to look at your Auto Layout constraints inside your storyboard.

[Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

Comment: My whole game is made in code does that change anything? Do I need constrains in code?

Comment: `self.label.needsUpdateConstraints()` this code will update your constraints